# SSIS Execute Process Task fails with SQL agent

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-job

I have a SSIS package with a Execute Process Task that runs an exe.  All code and executables are located on the same server.  The SSIS package runs inside the project but not when I upload to SSIS and run via SQL Server Agent.   Unsure why it wont run in the Agent.  Exe and package run fine by themselves but not in Agent.  Appreciate any help.  Below is the error I receive:

> Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility Version 10.50.6000.34
>   for 32-bit Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 2010. All rights
>   reserved.
>
> Started:  10:57:20 PM Error: 2018-10-19 10:57:43.83    Code:
>   0xC0029151    Source: Download XLS Execute Process Task
>   Description: In Executing "F:\Data
>   Imports\Office_Codes_monthly_download\EXE\PullOffices.exe" "" at
>   "F:\Data Imports\Office_Codes_monthly_download\EXE", The process exit
>   code was "255" while the expected was "0". End Error DTExec: The
>   package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1). Started:  10:57:20 PM
>   Finished: 10:57:43 PM Elapsed:  23.042 seconds

Comment: Is the executable in that location on the SQL Server? Does the user running the SQL Agent Job (most likely the service account) have access to the location and permissions to run the executable?

Comment: Maybe permissions?  Does the account running agent or if using a proxy account have access to the exe?

Comment: yes the exe is in that location on the same server as the SQL server.  I double checked the service account and it is an Admin with full permission to the folder and all contents.  Not using a proxy.

extra note....the exe will semi run.  as in it will start to replace my file but not finish.  so the file will have 0kb and wont open.   but if i run the exe myself the file will fully be replace and openable.

Comment: What is PullOffices.exe doing?

Comment: its downloading an xls file from a website and saving it to a location on the server

Comment: When you say the exe and package run fine by themselves or inside the project, which I assume is in visual studio, is that testing done on the server or on a local developer machine?  Is it possible to log onto the server and run the exe as the service account to rule out any issue it may have getting to the website and saving the file?

Comment: ^have not tried this yet.   will do now

Comment: Tim Mylott - great idea.   the service account had lan settings that were not allowing that the website to connect.  adjusted and fixed.

Comment: Great!  Glad we were able to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Try to pass the certificate information along with FTPES command like below.

```
open ftpes://FTPDDRIV:dr2pfile@dvlp.mvs.us.ups.com -explicit -certificate=xx:71:xx:xx:a2:eb:23:xx:xx:eb:xx:x:xx:xx:5d:74:4d:c2:c6:37
put D:\UPSdata\UPSDrive\Integration\document.txt
exit
```